# How to upgrade DD4T Java version 1 to 2?

Tags: dd4t

I have created WEB site by using DD4T Java 1.31. I'd like to upgrade DD4T to version 2. I heard DD4T 2 is compatible with DD4T 1. Is it possible by just replacing following JAR files to new version? Or is any other configuration required?

JAR files replaced to:

- dd4t-api.jar
- dd4t-core.jar
- dd4t-provider.jar

Regards,

Comment: Did you add any new jars like; dd4t-compatibility, dd4t-databind, dd4t-mvc-support, and update the dispatch servlet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DD4T-2 java is not backwards compatible with DD4T-1. The root cause is that the published XML has been updated; you would have to republish all your content. We've also changed deserialization frameworks, so you have to update several jarfiles. Finally, some internals have also been updated - the dispatcher-servlet and url-mapping xml files will be updating.

For reference, please checkout the dd4t-example-site in dd4t-2; its essentially the dd4t-1 example that's been fully updated and cleaned.

If you use DCP's, dd4t-compatibility would give you the old componentFactory API. You may want to consider using dd4t-databind if you want to take advantage of strongly typed models.